# I have a list in one class and I'm having trouble accessing it from another class C#

Tags: c#, list, class

I'm pretty new to C# and I'm stuck with a problem I've been trying to resolve for some time now.
I have to create classes for different types of food from a menu and input the values of the fields from the console. Problem is that the input is going to contain unknown count of each food type so I decided to use a List where I'm going to store the different types of, in this case, soups.

This is the code for the one of the food classes:

```
public class Soup : Food
{
    public List<Soup> soups = new List<Soup>();
    public Soup(string name, double grams, decimal price) : base(name, grams, price)
    {
    }
}
```

The code below is from the calling class. I'm receiving the input from the user but I'm stuck with accessing the list so I can add another element to it. 
I'd be very grateful if someone could give me some guidelines to access the list from the Soup class from the calling list so I can add the new element.

```
int countProducts = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
char[] delimeters = new char[] { ',', ' ' };
CultureInfo cultures = new CultureInfo("en-US");
for (int i = 0; i < countProducts; i++)
{
    string[] inputProductInfo = Console.ReadLine().ToLower().Split(delimeters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();
    if (inputProductInfo[0] == "soup")
    {
        Soup soup = new Soup(inputProductInfo[1], Convert.ToDouble(inputProductInfo[2], cultures), Convert.ToDecimal(inputProductInfo[3], cultures));
    }
}
```

Basicaly, I need to assing `soup` to the `soups` list but when I try the following code
`soups.Add(soup)`, I get the

> The name 'soups' does not exist in the current context
>   error.

EDIT: Leaving this edit here in case someone has the same problem after some time. I checked both of the suggestions below and both of them worked for me. However, I chose **li223**'s second suggested way as it was exactly what I was looking for. And the tip for altering the code was useful also.

Comment: FYI you don't have to change the title to "solved" -- if there is an accepted answer then we know that you got a solution for your problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference the list from your other object in some way. You can't just put the name of the member. There are 2 ways to do this.

Statically: You can make the List in the Soup class static which will let you do `Soup.soups`

```cs
public class Soup : Food
{
    public static List<Soup> soups = new List<Soup>();
}
```

```cs
var mysoup = new Soup(/*removed for brevity*/);
Soup.soups.Add(mysoup);
```

or you can create an instance your Soup class and access the member that way, which is almost what you have done anyway:

```cs
public class Soup : Food
{
    public List<Soup> soups = new List<Soup>();
}
```

```
var mysoupobj = new Soup(/*data*/);
mysoupobj.soups.Add(soup);
```

Edit:

Just wanted to note that every instance of your `Soup` class will also contain its own `List<Soup>`. I personally recommend that you alter your code such that the list inside `Soup` is instead somewhere else so that every instance of `Soup` wont have an empty `List<Soup>`

Answer (score 1):

The static member approach ~probably~ makes the most sense, but it's unclear from the problem description.

You could just make the Soup add itself to the static list from the constructor, then you don't need to worry about adding it from outside; every soup that gets created is added!

```
public class Soup : Food
{
    public static List<Soup> soups = new List<Soup>();
    public Soup(string name, double grams, decimal price) : base(name, grams, price)
    {
        soups.Add(this);
    }
}
```

Then access your list with:

```
Soup.soups.xxx();
```